# Passing parameters in oracle in c#(visual studio 2013)

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

Ok so i have searching everywhere and even though the solution is there I am unable to make it work.I am trying to bind the parameters but still i can see the command that is going to oracle is `"Select * from ParentInfo where Uname = :new ".`I have oracle 11g express edition.Please help as i am a newbie asp.net.
My code goes something like this

```
using System;   
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;   
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;   
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;   
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;    

namespace WebApplication4   
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page   
    {   
        string checkUser;   
        OracleDataReader reader;
        OracleDataReader rd; 
    protected void ButtonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("User ID=system;Password = oracle;Data Source=localhost:1521/XE");
        con.Open();
        checkUser = "Select * from ParentInfo where Uname = :new ";                     
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(checkUser, con);
        cmd.BindByName = true;            
        OracleParameter parameter = new OracleParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = ":new";
        parameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        parameter.Value = TextBoxUserName.Text; 
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);         
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Tried that too...still not working .

Comment: Do i need to add anything else for using DbType because it says DbType does not exist in the current context.

Comment: may be worth a try reader.Read(); ))  how do you read data from a query ?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ - i tried using System.Data.OracleClient .Still it says DbType does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @arndtdv - i use reader.read(); in my if and else condition which i forgot to post here .

Comment: @SearchAndResQ- still isnt working. BTW...everything is working fine when i concatinate the textbox in the select statement.Only when i use the parameterized query it gives this issue.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ - Didnt work either .Thanx anyways :)

Comment: may be set: cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

Comment: @arndtdv-     it says the name 'CommandType' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: in package manager console: Install-Package odp.net.managed   and rebuild

Comment: @arndtdv - installed and rebuilt.Still the same ..says CommandType' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this post is old, but it may help others. I think the problem is in

```
parameter.ParameterName = ":new";
```

while the parameter name should be without colon (:)

```
parameter.ParameterName = "new";
```